# get the enclosing type of an [enum member?]

Tags: c++

```
struct class1
{
    enum res
    {
        a = 9,
        b = 15
    };

    class1(res e) { }
};

struct class2
{
    enum res
    {
        he = 5,
        de = 2
    };

    class2(res e) {}
};

template<typename T, typename E>
void fn(E e)
{
    foo(T(e));
}
```

This function works, I can call it like `fn<class2>(class2::he));` for example, but I don't want to explicitly specify `class2` twice.

Is there a way to deduce the type "class2" based on `class2::he`?

Comment: I don't now if such way exists, but at least there is a bit dirty workaround: You can replace enums with classes with `static constexpr` consts and something like `using base = /*class1 or class2*/;` inside.

Comment: How would you distinguish `class C1 { enum E1 {} }; class C2 { using E2 = C1::E1}` from `class C2 { enum E2 {} }; class C1 { using E1 = C2::E2}` ? C++ has a subtle distinction between types and names. In particular, one type may have multiple (nested) names. Type deduction in templates gives you a type and yet another name for that type. (here `typename T`)

Answer (score 0):

How about defining some helper meta functions to get the type you want?

```
#include <type_traits>

struct class1
{
    enum res
    {
        a = 9,
        b = 15
    };

    class1(res e) { }
};

struct class2
{
    enum res
    {
        he = 5,
        de = 2
    };

    class2(res e) {}
};

auto get_enclosing_type(class1::res) -> class1;
auto get_enclosing_type(class2::res) -> class2;

template <typename T>
using get_enclosing_type_t = decltype(get_enclosing_type(std::declval<T>()));

template<typename E>
void fn(E const e)
{
    using type = get_enclosing_type_t<E>;
    foo(type {e});
}
```